# Error when creating project in VS: No sfdx-project.json found in the root directory of your open project. Open a Salesforce DX project in VS Code

Tags: visualstudiocode

No sfdx-project.json found in the root directory of your open project. Open a Salesforce DX project in VS Code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sfdx-project.json found in the root directory of your open project. Open a Salesforce DX project in VS Code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240747/no-sfdx-project-json-found-in-the-root-directory-of-your-open-project-open-a-sa)

Comment: I tried but no luck

Comment: sfdcfox suggests two solutions, 吴烜_中文编程 suggests a third. Have you tried all these, always getting the same result?

Comment: Yes I tried all but not able to create a project